# whatsapp hyperlink - combine whatsapp://send? with intent://send/

Tags: android, html, iphone, whatsapp

It's possible to have a button in my web page, for sending pre-filled messages to specific number?

i'm trying with

```
intent://send/+391234567890#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end;whatsapp://send?text=
```

nothing result.

have a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write the **country code without +**

```
<a href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Message me in WhatsApp</a>
```

Sadly this does not work unless the number is **already in your contacts** list! Making it useless.

Here's what happens for me: I get a modal dialog saying the user is not on WhatsApp and I can either **Invite** or **SMS**. This is a mistake - they're DEFINITELY on WhatsApp, but not in my contacts because I've deleted them for testing.

#### Workaround idea

1. Offer vCard to save to Contacts

Since the phone number has to be in the Contacts list first, let's get it there. Track the site visitor to see if it's the first time she tapped on *Contact me on WhatsApp* (a cookie?). If it's the first time she tapped, make the link download your vCard

```
href="johnsmith.vcf"
```

The user now has to open the downloaded vCard with the People app, and add you to her Contacts.

2. Android intents URI FTW

When she returns, assuming she added you, make the button work with the `intent://` URI scheme.

```
href="intent://send/391234567890#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end"
```

She taps on it and is magically transported to a WhatsApp chat with you.

3. Keep track of which `href` to present

Hopefully you can use the cookie you set to track her so you don't have the button offer the vCard AGAIN. There's no other way to know if your number is in her Contacts list unless you ask. But then it's not a button anymore, it's a form.

Same goes for Telegram. Security implications are probably the ones keeping Instant Messaging not so instant.